# Nuxt does not load proper css in first load

Tags: npm, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxtjs/vuetify and I used the command npm run generate and uploaded it to my server. In the first load, It doesn't show the right theme for my nuxt app.

[image: First load of website]

After I reload again, it shows the proper color of my website.
[image]